# Ionic Live Reload not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Live Reload has stopped working.

When I save code changes, the browser automatically refreshes, but code changes are not reflected. I need to stop my CLI and run `ionic serve` again in order to have any code changes reflected in the browser.

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

Comment: Should I run the following? can it cause any damage?  `sudo npm install -g ionic`

Comment: using sudo doesnt do any damage..,at first uninstall it and then re-install the ionic project. it should work fine

Comment: Will uninstalling and reinstalling ionic solve the live reload issue?

Comment: just close CLI, open it again, then use ionic serve... it will work

Comment: Nope, I closed and quit the terminal. ran `ionic serve --livereload`. But still have the same issue.

Comment: @Richard try to do (uninstalling)..,it doesnt take time..,just try it out

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling ionic `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic` and `sudo npm install -g ionic`. Also tried rebooting my mac.  Still not working.

Comment: can you create a new ionic2 project and see that?

Comment: Thanks @Sampath. Good suggestion. I created a new ionic project, and live reload does work. So this means there must be an issue with my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is with your current project.So please create a new project like below.

```
ionic start myfirstapp blank --v2
```

After that see whether live reload is working or not.It should work now.

```
ionic serve
```

**Note:** If above one is working then you can `copy/ paste` your previous project's custom items where you have created to this project.Hope that solution will be much quicker than try to find a solution with the old project.That is my idea.

Comment: Thanks @Sampath. Good suggestion. I created a new ionic project, and live reload does work. So this means there must be an issue with my project.  How do I diagnose/fix the current project?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the solution. How do I diagnose the issue on my current project?  Or should I create a new project, and copy my old on to it?

Comment: Yes, You just need to copy your custom items which you have included in your previous project.That procedure should be quicker than try to find a solution for the reload issue.Those are very time-consuming things to do.Hence those are framework related things.may be JS file corruption or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: My problem is, I copied my old src/pages to the new app, and now livereload does not work again. I guess that means there is a bug in my code.

Comment: Do your copy/paste thing one by one while live reload is running.Then you can easily find the defect code file at the time when it brakes.  @Richard

Comment: I have noticed, this only happens in one html file I am trying to update. This html file, is referenced by a number of ts files that share the common html. Maybe, because the other ts files still have a handle on this html file, its is not releasing it.

Comment: Great.Then check whether is there any open/close brackets issue. @Richard

Answer (score 0):

I did these to resolve this error on my ubuntu

1. Remove the npm_folder and package-lock.json files
2. Run npm install --save-dev
3. Restart your system